# In Xcode, how to make a standalone UI Test to refer to previous project

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing

When I generate a Single View project at IOS platform, UITest would automatically come along with this project. But how could I make a standalone UITest file, and then refer to the source project to make a test?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you want to create and new UITest file then create a UI Test Case class from file menu option and after naming it select Target as the UITestTarget from your project.